# How to run a python script 24/7 with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Good afternoon,

I have an issue. I'm a starter python programmer and for one of my clients for which I make very high-level spreadsheets I wrote a python script that uses selenium webdriver to obtain a data file from a website. However, this file has to run every morning at 7:00 and I would like to know if there is any way to keep this script running 24/7 so that it can perform it's tasking every morning at 7:00.
Optionally I have a raspberry pi 4 to use however I have never used it for anything so far it is still boxed.

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [crontab](https://crontab.guru/)

```
0 7 * * * yourScriptCommand
```

Comment: So you are suggesting that I run a linux based operating system on my raspberry pi and use crontab to make the raspberry pi run the script every day at 07:00?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into renting a cheapish cloud server (from digitalocean for example). There are multiple ways of transferring data from your python script to your bot, either directly, through a websocket, or a webpage that displays it in a JSON format or otherwise.

Since you're already using python you could look into running a flask app on your node alongside your script or even combine them together.

If ran separately you could modify your script to output it's content into a file and then read the file with your flask application to display it on a webpage.
For example:

```
with open('/tmp/data.txt', 'w') as f:
f.write(yourdata)
```

then in your flask application:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_data():
with open('/tmp/data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
return data
```

Comment: The data comes from downloading a file from a site, so it requires 'clicking' a download button to get the file. Then it transfers the file to a folder. Reads it with pandas and uploads it to a spreadsheet in google using gspread. Is it possible to download such a file with like a http request or with bs4?

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, i think, that for your script will running 24/7 you can use web host(PythonAnyWhere(he's free)), and that for your script make some tasks in 7:00 o'clock, you can make condition in your script with datetime module. make loop while for that your script to be pending, kinda this:

```
while(time != 7:00): 
    pass 
    if time == 7:00:
        do something
```

Comment: The problem I have is that my script has a selenium webdriver. Which requires a version of chrome driver to be launched and to visit a web page. I don't think web host's support that

Comment: I'm not sure, but for that you can search in google for more info.

Comment: PythonAnywhere does support Selenium, but with a free account you'd be limited to accessing sites on a whitelist (https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/), so you'd need to use a paid account to scrape any sites that are not on that list.